# Prove the statement A ⊗ (A ⊗ B) = B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So im supposed to prove that the statement A ⊗ (A ⊗ B) = B is true. I've been trying different ways to prove it but nothing seems to be working, and im getting some nonsense results. Can someone please help me with this?

edit:
I think the ⊗ symbol means exclusive or, but as for what A and B are i have no clue, this is all the information i was presented.

Comment: This is false. Take $B=\Bbb Q$ and $A=\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. We have $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}=0$, a contradiction to your statement.

Comment: What operation do you mean by ⊗ here? It has many different meanings in many different branches of mathematics.

Comment: What does the symbol mean? Exclusive Or?

Comment: And what are $A$ and $B$ actually? This would be helpful, too.

Comment: You say you "think" ⊗ is "xor" but aren't sure?  And you don't know what A and B are?  "⊗" and certainly "A" and "B" can have many meaning in mathematics and the answer to this question depend strongly on what they mean here!  Where did you get this?  What course is it from?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclusive Or is associative
2. A xor A is false
3. B xor false is B